What I am doing wrong? Finding exact value of sum
We Want to find using power series the exact value of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{5^{n-1}}    $. Wolfram says that the value is $1,34$ approx.
Now, we know that :
$ \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n $
We differentiate both sides :
$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}$
Multiply by $x$:
$ \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n}$
And differentiate again :
$ \frac{-x-1}{(1-x)^3} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n^2x^{n-1}$
Now, if we evaluate $ \frac{-x-1}{(1-x)^2}$ at $x=\frac{1}{5}$ the value is $2,34$ approx. That is, one more than the value of the series. In fact $2,34$ is the value of the series but starting at $n=1$.
What I am doing wrong? I can’t find my mistake.
Thanks.

in the last step, why $n=2$ and not $n=1$?

@SineoftheTime Because I differentiate two times. Why is that wrong?

Isn’t true that differentiation shift index? Why the second differentiation does not increases the index?

if you differentiate $nx^{n-1}$, then you get $n(n-1)x^{n-2}$ and the "index is shifted" because at $n=1$ you have a $0$ term. But here you have $nx^n$and when you differentiate you get $n^2x^{n-1}$ which is non zero when $n=1$

Write out the first three or four terms of the sum in longhand and you'll see why the comments are correct.

No... differentiation does NOT shift index.... ever.... Here you have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$ and you differentiate and you get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^{n-1}$.   When $n=0$ we have $nx^{n-1} = 0 \times \frac 1x = 0$.  So $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^{n-1}= 0 + 1\cdot x^0 + 2\cdot x^1 + 3\cdot x^2+ .... = 0 +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1}$.  The was no shift.  Now if we want we can note that if $n=1$ then $nx^{n-1}=1\cdot x^0 = 1$ so we could rewrite as $1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty nx^{n-1}$ but there really isn't any point.

After you "differentiate again" the sum still starts at $n=1$, not at the $n=2$ you want.
"Shift the index" is not a rule. It's just usually correct. In this case you are differentiating
$$
x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + \cdots
$$
to get
$$
1 + 4x + 9x^2 + \cdots .
$$
The series you ask about starts at the $4x$ term.
I recommend writing out such sums with the first few terms followed by the ellipsis rather than formally manipulating the $\Sigma$.

Isn’t true that differentiation shift index? Why the second differentiation does not increases the index?

@UDAC See my edit.
